# Dart_LoadScriptFromKernel: The binary program does not contain 'main'

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I just run this code in VsCode and show this problem

> Dart_LoadScriptFromKernel: The binary program does not contain 'main'.

Dart version:2.3.2

```dart
void main() {
  print("hello");
}
```

is there any wrong with configuration?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Upload a screenshot. It's working fine from my end dart version: 2.3.2 in VSCode

Comment: Does it run properly if you run `dart main.dart` (being in the file directory)?

Comment: I'm getting this error    ```Error: Error when reading 'main.dart': No such file or directory``` @Mattia

Comment: @Patel123 You might not be in the main.dart directory.

Comment: For future readers, note the file in the screenshot is marked with a dot next to its name. This means the file contains unsaved changes. By default, VS Code does not automatically save changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try saving it in your folder it works 100% and name it main

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Code, this error happens when you are trying to run your main.dart file, but you have another window (or tab) open with a class file for example. Make sure when you run your code you have the main (main.dart) tab open with your main function in it.

Comment: I had two vscode instances opened. Worked when closed the other one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the extension.
   2.Then, click on Reload Required.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTHc6.png
2. Enable extension.

Answer (score 1):

1. On Visual Studio Click on "View"
2. Then click on Run
3. Then on the left top corner see run drop-down menu
4. select add configuration.
5. Then a JSON file appears.
6. Now delete everything and paste the below:

```
 {    
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart: Attach to Process",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "attach"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "bin/main.dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dart: Run all Tests",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./test/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dart: Attach to Process",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "attach"
        },

        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "program": "bin/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ] }
```

7. Now again go to let hand side top and see beside run there is a play
   type button.
8. Just press it and allow permission
9. Now run the code in the terminal.
   It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. Then I found that I did not save the file (code). Then I save it (ctrl+s or File > Save). Finally I run the command

```
dart hello.dart
```

and get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

VScode always requires a `main.dart` file in the project directory with at least the minimum contents:

```
void main() {}
```

With that file present, you can then name any other file you're working on, and execute it directly from the VScode console using eg. `dart hello_world.dart` (with example contents):

```
void main() {
  print("Hello World");
}
```

and the `main.dart` file does *not* need to be open when this is done.

Answer (score -1):

you have to do is just save the file ctrl+s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982182/2227743

Answer (score -1):

ctrl + s please. you don't save this file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).